# Centered Grid view css and different window sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to apply a more consistent styling to my site with css, but I'm a little bit lost, hope you can help.

### **Current situation:**

- div `#post-area` containing 3 columns of posts on a normal/big window or screensize
- div `#post-area` is centered
- **Problem**: When you decrease the width of the window, it becomes a 2-column view way too early, even though still 3 posts could be displayed.

### **Desired situation:**

- div `#post-area` containing 3 columns of posts on a normal/big window or screensize
- div `#post-area` is centered
- centered position of `#post-area` disappears more and more as you decrease the window size and just when there really is not enough space for 3 posts next to each other, **then** 2 posts next to each other should be displayed

This is my div container:

```
  #post-area {
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 260px;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
  }
```

Now, I could solve the problem by just deleting all the `width` and `margin: auto;` tags but then the content *would not be centered* anymore!

**Question**:
How do I get centered content but still proper display on smaller window sizes?

Thank you so much, I really really appreciate your help.

[My Website](http://sparschweinkiller.de/)

**EDIT** I figured maybe you can help better if you had my code, so: Here is my index.php:

```html
<div id="post-area">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
    
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    
 endwhile; ?>
    
    
</div>
```

And here is my content.php:

```html
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
   
            <div class="gridly-copy">
                
                
         
                
                
                
                  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
       
         
            <?php    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'summary-image' ); // returns an array

?>
         
                
               
                
                 <div class="gridly-image">
                           
                <img class="wpimagehover alignnone wp-image-<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id() ?>" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="" width="300" height="250" data-fburl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-tweeturl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-pinurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-stumbleuponurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-sstyle="circle" data-sharetxt="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" data-animation="fade" /> 
                   
                </div>

                
                <div><h2><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                           
                
          <!-- <div class="gridly-category"><p><?php the_category(', ') ?></p></div>
            -->
    <?php } ?>
          
            <!-- POS TITLE -->
            
             <!--   <p class="gridly-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> 
            
</p>  -->

<div class="contentbox"> <?php the_content('<span class="moretext">(Mehr lesen...)</span>'); ?> </div>

   <!--Preis Anzeige  -->                 

  <div class="price">
      <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'preis', true); echo ' ' ?> </div>
                    

          
                    
   <!--Sparschwein killen button  -->                 
  <div class="sparbutton">              
    <?php 
    $linkadress = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afflink', true);

        echo do_shortcode( '[otw_shortcode_button href="' . $linkadress. '"             size="medium" bgcolor="#d11112"  icon_position="left" shape="radius" target="_blank"]Sparschwein Killen[/otw_shortcode_button]' ) ?> 

</div>

                
                    
                    
        
                    
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think this code will fix your problem

```
 #post-area {
    width: 100%;//modified
    margin:0 auto;//modified
    padding-top: 260px;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    }

    #post-area .post {
    width: 24%;//modified
    background: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;//added
    }
```

Try this below code only css if the content merging together

```
 .contentbox {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 105px;
    width: 80%;//added width
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks for you help but unfortunately it did not work. 
With your code when making the window smaller the content merges together and when making the window wider the spaces _between_ posts increase, and not the spaces on the right and left hand side of my #post-area, which would then centralize the whole container.
I posted some more of my code above, maybe that helps.